# c# windows authentication for a asp.net web interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, authentication, identity

I need to do windows authentication for a web interface asp.net.
I have set up config authentication mode equal to windows.

For windows authentication, we need to set up only this:
- `<authentication mode="Windows" />`

and in IIS we need to:
-remove anonymous access
-check integrated windows authentication.

Do we need to any other thing for windows authentication?
How to get username for validating in c#?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, nothing else is required for windows authentication (assuming you only need authentication and not impersonation) in an asp.net application.
You can now get the user's identity from

```
(WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
```